# Duplicated trait imported on php class

Tags: php, traits

I have three classes and two traits:

- I need that Base class have trBase->load() method to 'Load Basic'.
- I need that Advanced class have trAdvanced->load() method to 'Load Advanced' and 'Load Basic'.
- I need that Zero class have trAdvanced->load() method to 'Load Advanced' and 'Load Basic'.

Because Zero class don't extends from Base class, I have to be sure that this and another classes using trAdvanced trait 'imports or use' also trBase trait. Then I have added `use Trait trBase` to trait trAdvanced. 
Now, Advanced class seems to have two times the code of trAdvanced, because I'm getting two times 'Loading Advanced' and 'Loading Basic', and I can see two times Advanced->init() method on debugger call stack.

There is one method to use one Trait only if not it's 'used/imported' by one parent class?

```
class Base
{
    use Trait trBase;

    function init()
    {
        echo('Starting');
    }
}

class Medium extends class Base
{
}

class Advanced extends class Medium
{
    use Trait trAdvanced
}

class Zero
{
    use Trait trAdvanced
}

trait trBase
{
    function init()
    {
        parent::init();

        $this->load();
    }

    function load()
    {
        echo('Loading Basic');
    }
}

trait trAdvanced
{
    use trBase;

    function load()
    {
        echo('Loading Advanced');
        parent::load();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i hope this sample code useful for you :

```
<?php

class Base
{
    use  trBase;

    function init()
    {
        echo('Starting');
    }
}

class Medium extends  Base
{
}

class Advanced extends  Medium
{
    use trAdvanced;
}

class Zero
{


    use trAdvanced, trBase {
        trAdvanced::load as trAdvancedLoad;
        trBase::load insteadof trAdvanced;
    }
}

trait trBase
{
    function init()
    {
        parent::init();

    }

    function load()
    {
        echo('Loading Basic');
    }
}

trait trAdvanced
{

    function load()
    {
        echo('Loading Advanced');
    }
}


# --------------------------------------------------
//$base_obj=new Base();
//printf($base_obj->load());
# --------------------------------------------------

$zero_obg=new Zero();
printf($zero_obg->load() , $zero_obg->trAdvancedLoad());
```

Comment: Thank you for your code. I want to 'import' 'trBase' on trAdvance to can use `trAdvanced` trait on any class without having to worry about his parent classes have 'imported' 'trBase'. With your code, if I change parent of Medium or parent of Advanced, trBase never will be 'imported'.